# Is it a security risk to publicly show a user's socket.io socket ID?

Tags: reactjs, rest, socket.io, session-storage, websecurity

I have a React chatting application where I'm required to let my API know which socket connection called the API. Because of that, I need to reference the user's current socket ID somewhere on the client-side.

Would it be safe to store the user's socket ID in session storage, and would it matter if another user knew that user's current socket ID?

Would they be able to somehow use the stolen socket ID in their own socket connection to pretend they're them?